# Can't set duplicate attributes in CSS call to jQueryLite

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg

How to set duplicate attributes in a single CSS call to jQueryLite? In angular, I want to do something like this on an SVG image:

```
element.css({'transform': "rotate("+rot*360+"deg)",'transform': "scale("+scl+")"});
```

This sets both the rotation and the scale of an SVG image. However, the result is that the last 'transform' attribute overwrites any previous ones. I.e., I can set the scale or the rotation but not both.

In this example, the expected css would look like:

```
transform: rotate(360deg); transform: scale(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JavaScript or jQueryLite – in a stylesheet, multiple declarations for the same property would overwrite each other as well.

The *correct* syntax to specify multiple transformations is

```
transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1)
```

Comment: Ah so simple. My question was so dumb. Thank you for the prompt answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a CSS property to two completely different values at the same time.

If you wrote:

```
transform: rotate(360deg); transform: scale(1)
```

then the second value would overwrite the first one and it would end up being the same as

```
transform: scale(1)
```

The transform property takes a space separated list of values. You would need to write:

```
transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1);
```

and, in theory, you do exactly the same in your JS:

```
element.css({'transform': "rotate("+rot*360+"deg) scale("+scl+")"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not merging those by:

```
element.css({'transform': "rotate("+rot*360+"deg) scale("+scl+")"});
```